# Dell Latitude 5590 Trackpoint not listed in xinput list

Tags: debian, input, libinput

I recently installed Debian 9 on my new Dell Latitude 5590 notebook when I realized the pointing stick as well as the three buttons above the touchpad do not work. They work in Ubuntu out of the box.

But in Debian the input is not even listed in `xinput`:

```
- Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
 -  Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
  - DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad              id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

- Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
   - Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   - Power Button                               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   - Video Bus                                  id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   - Power Button                               id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   - Sleep Button                               id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   - Integrated_Webcam_HD                       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   - Intel HID events                           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard               id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   - Dell WMI hotkeys                           id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The virtual core pointer should actually list another item:

```
- "DualPoint Stick"
```

Is there a way I can see if the input is even recognized by the kernel?

`dmesg` output pasted here: https://pastebin.com/AmQR5d93

`Xorg.1.log` output pasted here: https://pastebin.com/8JqMKADV

*After updating to buster/sid with apt-pinning:*

`dmesg` output: https://pastebin.com/2QcN2FVn

`Xorg.1.log` ouput: https://pastebin.com/XWrdB8QV

Comment: Boot Ubuntu, have a look at `dmesg` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (if you are using X and not Wayland) to see how the touchpad hardware is recognized, and which driver it uses. Install the same drivers in Debian, see if it works.

Comment: @dirkt After checking dmesg I found out the kernel module for the trackpoint pci device is: `intel_lpss_pci`. How do you now properly install the driver on Debian?

Comment: That's not the trackpoint PCI device, that's an I2C controller. The trackpoint is likely behind it (and may use an additional interface on top of I2C). Please figure out the whole hierarchy, or put the whole `dmesg` output and Xorg.log in a pastebin etc. and edit question with link.

Comment: Ah i see. Sorry for any my missing knowledge, i am quite new in this world. I added the contents of dmesg and Xorg.log aswell.

Comment: Upgrade to kernel 4.19.xx or above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same machine and also installed Debian 9 on it.

On a plain vanilla install you need to install this:

```
apt-get install build-essential && gcc && g++ && linux-headers-$(uname -r) && bison && flex && bc && libssl-dev && libelf-dev
```

I think I've got'em all now... if I've forgotten something it'll complain further on - if so install missing package.

Next you download the latest kernel from kernel.org and extract it.
At the time I write this it is `4.17.10`

cd to the extracted folder eg

```
root@e5590:/home/****/kernelCompile/linux-4.17.10/linux-4.17.10# ls
arch        Documentation  Kbuild   mm       scripts     vmlinux
block       drivers    Kconfig  modules.builtin  security    vmlinux.o
built-in.a  firmware       kernel   modules.order    sound
certs       fs         lib      Module.symvers   System.map
COPYING     include    LICENSES net      tools
CREDITS     init       MAINTAINERS  README       usr
crypto      ipc        Makefile samples      virt
```

next search for the `.config` in the kernel header files you installed eg

```
find / -name .config
```

it'll show you where it is so...

now copy the `.config` to the current folder eg

```
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-7-amd64/.config .
```

next you issue:

```
make -j$(nproc)
```

it'll ask you A LOT :) - in our case just keep pushing enter accepting all the defaults

It'll start building... be patient...

Once it's done you do this:

```
make modules_install
```

and then

```
make install
```

once it's done issue

```
reboot
```

you'll see it booting with the new kernel - you'll also notice that the wifi driver errors are gone and you 'll have trackpoint and touchpad functional - like me... I really do like my trackpoint :)

EDIT: fix the pc speaker error during boot by adding

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

to

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

this way it's 100% ok.

I hope it'll work out for you.

kind regards

Comment: That does it! Many thanks mate :-) Even though I do not use the tracking point that often, but I like it when everything works. Ty again!

Comment: The basic answer is that kernel 4.15.xx (and below) doesn't fully support it while 4.19.xx does, so a kernel upgrade is required for, say, Debian/stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Googling for "044E:121F Touchpad" (the vendor and device id) finds a dmesg dump with lines like

```
1523306746.828230  input: DELL0817:00 044E:121F as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-DELL0817:00/0018:044E:121F.0001/input/input9
1523306746.828384  hid-generic 0018:044E:121F.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [DELL0817:00 044E:121F] on i2c-DELL0817:00
1523306746.868226  input: DELL0817:00 044E:121F Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-DELL0817:00/0018:044E:121F.0001/input/input10
1523306746.868387  input: DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-DELL0817:00/0018:044E:121F.0001/input/input11
1523306746.868444  input: DELL0817:00 044E:121F UNKNOWN as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-DELL0817:00/0018:044E:121F.0001/input/input12
1523306746.868503  input: DELL0817:00 044E:121F UNKNOWN as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-DELL0817:00/0018:044E:121F.0001/input/input13
1523306746.868574  input: DELL0817:00 044E:121F UNKNOWN as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-DELL0817:00/0018:044E:121F.0001/input/input14
1523306746.868631  hid-multitouch 0018:044E:121F.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [DELL0817:00 044E:121F] on i2c-DELL0817:00
```

So *likely* this is a HID over I2C device, and you need kernel modules for the I2C controller (your `intel_lpss_pci`, in this dump it was a different controller), and you also need `i2c-hid` and `hid-multitouch`.

Kernel modules are in the kernel, so you either need to compile your own kernel for Debian 9 with those modules enabled, or pin your apt to Debian 9 (google "apt pinning"), add newer Debian distributions to apt, and install a newer kernel from those in the hope it includes the modules by default.

Looking at your Ubuntu kernel version may also help.

**Edit**

Your second `Xorg.1.log`, if it is the correct one, shows that X recognizes your touchpad:

```
[   718.090] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad (/dev/input/event10)
[   718.091] (**) DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[   718.091] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad'
[   718.091] (**) DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad: always reports core events
[   718.091] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[   718.091] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   718.092] (II) input device 'DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad', /dev/input/event10 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   718.092] (II) input device 'DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad', /dev/input/event10 is a touchpad
[   718.112] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-7/i2c-DELL0817:00/0018:044E:121F.0001/input/input10/event10"
[   718.112] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 11)
[   718.113] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   718.113] (**) DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   718.113] (**) DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   718.113] (**) DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   718.114] (II) input device 'DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad', /dev/input/event10 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   718.114] (II) input device 'DELL0817:00 044E:121F Touchpad', /dev/input/event10 is a touchpad
```

For some reason, it looks like it's adding it twice, though. The second dmesg also shows the drivers are properly initialized. So *something* changed. Can you see it with `xinput` now? If you can't, possibly adding it twice screwed something up, but that's the first time I've seen this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however i find compiling an own kernel a bit of an overkill, is there nothing else you can do? :o (besides waiting until the necessary modules are added by default). For Ubuntu i used 18.04.

Comment: You need a kernel with the correct modules. Besides building one yourself, and using one of those provided by Debian, I don't think there are any other choices ... As I wrote, you can "mix" Debian 9 (stable = stretch) with newer ones (testing = buster, or sid) via apt-pinning; Debian stable is quite "conservative". This means you can have a newer kernel *right now* without having to upgrade your complete distro.

Comment: Thanks for the Information, I did update to buster/sid now, but unfortunally nothing changed. I added the `dmesg` and `Xorg.1.log` output to the question if you find time to check them, there is no mentioning of any pointing stick - like device though. :( I guess thats it then, I am not really comfortable yet adding the modules and compiling the kernel all by myself.